How do I get the content of notifications when app is opened from notification?

I can successfully receive the remote notification using the huawei_push flutter package. It has a title and description like I set on AppGallery Connect.
Now, when I click the notification it opens the app and it triggers onNotificationOpenedApp stream if app is already active otherwise need to take notification form getInitialNotification when app opens.
When I get a notification using either stream or from the initial notification callback both give me Map with null values for all the keys.
I am using these two methods for getting the notification contents while the user clicks on the notification.
// Set up notification opened app handler
  Push.onNotificationOpenedApp.listen(_onNotificationOpenedApp);
  // Check for initial notification
  final dynamic initialNotification = await Push.getInitialNotification();
  _onNotificationOpenedApp(initialNotification);

